Altium annotation - no changes were made
Although I have made changes in the schematic file in Altium, it tells me that there is no change in the annotation process, but there is.

What is this caused by, and how to solve it?

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

The "Annotate" tool is for setting reference designators, and has no bearing on other schematic changes... are you sure you're expecting a change? Can you scroll through the list and look for any ?, gaps or duplicates? ... Perhaps you meant to click "Reset All" first?

Have you tried going to Tools -> Annotate -> Force annotate all schematics?

You want to try and have it look for more changes than just comments and library reference. Altium will only generate changes on what you tell it to check. That goes for ECOs and DRC checks.
